# PERL: ref, shift keyword

Tags: perl

I am going through the following subroutine:

```
sub new{
    my $self  = shift;
    my $class = ref($self) || $self;
}
```

Here, I don't understand what does `shift` is used for? What I understand from googling is that, `shift` returns and deletes the leftmost value of the array. But still I am not sure.

Another question, what does `ref` is used for? Google says it acts as `typeof` function that returns the type like `scalar`, `array`, `hashes`.

Still I am not sure about my understanding. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html and http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html

I'm not a huge fan of pasting links but these will answer your questions.

Comment: With my best intentions: I would suggest that you read up on this from a coherent source.  This is important stuff, Googling quick answers won't cut it for the future.  Nor will short SO posts, unless somebody is willing to write a tutorial.  But they are out there already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a subroutine in Perl any arguments you supply will be available to the subroutine in a special array called `@_`.

The `shift` function takes an array as an argument, removes the first element from the array and returns that value.

However, if you call `shift` without passing it an array, it operates on the `@_` array.

So for example if you call a subroutine like this:

```
my_sub('one', 'two', 'three');
```

And the definition of `my_sub` starts like this:

```
sub my_sub {
    my $arg1 = shift;
```

Then the `$arg1` variable will contain the string `'one'` and the `@_` array will be left with `('two', 'three')`.

The code you're trying to understand seems to relate to object oriented coding.  If you call a method on an object like this:

```
$obj->my_method('one');
```

Then the `my_method` subroutine will actually be passed two arguments in `@_`.  The first is the object that the method was invoked on (sometimes called the `invocant`) which in this example is `$obj`.  The second argument will be the string `'one'`.

It is very common in object-oriented code to start a method definition like this:

```
sub my_method {
    my $self = shift;
```

Which means `$self` will now contain the invocant and `@_` will be left with all the remaining arguments.

In your specific example, you were looking at a constructor which is a special kind of method.  Usually it would be called like this:

```
my $my_obj = MyClass->new($arg1, $arg2);
```

In which case the invocant will be the name of the class that the `new` method was invoked on - the string `'MyClass'` in this example.

It would also be possible to invoke the constructor function on an existing object like this:

```
my $new_obj = $my_obj->new($arg1, $arg2);
```

Exactly what the result of this call should be is not at all clear to the casual reader.  Should it be a completely new object that is a clone of `$my_obj` or should it be a new object that has nothing in common with `$my_obj` at all?  In the first case, defining a `clone` method would be clearer and in the second case, calling the constructor on the class would be clearer.

Your example code is trying to handle these two cases.  If the invocant is a class then `ref($self)` will return `undef` since a plain string (the class name) is not a reference.  If the invocant is an object, then `ref($self)` will return the name of the class that the object is an instance of.

If you're trying to grok Perl's native support for OO programming then start with [the standard tutorial doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html).  If you just want to do OO programming with Perl then start with [Moose](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual.pod).